# Write_ods keeps writing an empty data frame into directory?

Tags: r, ods

I am trying to export a data frame into an ods sheet, however it is not working correctly.

I have tried exporting the information to many different directories but all have failed. I have also been able to use read_ods in the correct way. When using write_ods I keep getting zero errors yet the directory I am writing to is always empty after I open it.

```r
print(final)
write_ods(x = final, path = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/SpendingOptimizerStreamlined/CoeffSheet.ods")
temp <- read_ods(path = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/SpendingOptimizerStreamlined/CoeffSheet.ods")
print(temp)
```

I have printed the final data frame that I want to export and it is full of the correct data.
I then write to the directory and get no errors.
To confirm that the previous command worked correctly, I then read in the previously exported data.
Then I print the data out and see zero columns and zero rows.

Not quite sure why this keeps happening? I am curious to know if the write_ods command is still supported or am I just doing something wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Does this happen with other data.frames too or just this one?

Comment: All data frames. I have tried using the iris one as well

Comment: Does this return TRUE? `file.exists("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/SpendingOptimizerStreamlined/")`

Comment: Its returning false

Comment: Obviously,  it is not writing the file. I wonder if that could be because you are writing to the home directory of Administrator.  Could this be about write permissions?  Try writing to the directory of you as a user, not Administrator.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, and can't figure out the reason why. I am not even working to an administration folder, but to one of my data folders, with permission for my user also (the only one in the computer). I tried with simpler paths (no Spanish accents and no spaces) with no result...

Comment: I even tried with a very simple data.frame ( data.frame(A = letters[1:10], B= 1:10) ) and very simple path D:/Active with the same result: no message, no warning, but the file is not created (not at least at the desired folder).

Comment: I kept trying...and the cause was simple. I just assumed the function would automatically append the file extension and did not include it. When adding .ods at the end of the file name it worked smoothly.